# Add check items to listView

Tags: .net, winforms

How to add checked items to listView?

in .net2 window form

this sample works, but items are not checked

```
listView.Items.Add(
    new ListViewItem(new string[] { folderBrowser.SelectedPath }, group_1));
```

this sample doesn't work, i want to add checked items

```
listView.Items.Add(
    new ListViewItem(
        new string[] { folderBrowser.SelectedPath },
        group_1))
        .Checked(true);
```

thankyou.

Comment: What are you using? WinForms? ASP.NET? WPF? Something else? What's wrong with your current code? What exactly are “check items”?

Comment: Maybe you want a CheckedListBox? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(new string[] { folderBrowser.SelectedPath }, group_1);
lvi.Checked = true;
listView.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C# 3 or newer (Visual Studio 2008 or newer), you can use object initializer:

```
listView.Items.Add(
    new ListViewItem(
        new string[] { folderBrowser.SelectedPath },
        group_1))
        { Checked = true };
```